# Why electric generators in turbojet engine always need reduction gearing?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

The rotor of the turbojet engine is rotating with average speeds from 15 000 to 150 000 rpms, depending on size.

Why reduction gearing is used to drive the generator? Why it is not common, or probably inpractical, to use permament magnets mounted on the shaft and rotating with such speed, and stationary coils? This would probably save some lossed in reduction gears?

I think there is some **fundamental obstacle** to gearless solution, e.g. back-EMF rising sharply at higher RPMs. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Back-Emf is when you are powering a motor. This is probably a question of the trade-off between not wanting the output frequency to be to high and the impracticality of the number of output phase being too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator's AC output frequency is a small-integer multiple of the
rotation rate.  High rotation rates for generators are avoided because efficient magnetic materials (iron, basically) have AC
losses related to electrical conductivity (eddy currents).   At frequencies of
50 Hz-1 kHz they are efficient and make lightweight high-power-output
generators and motors.  From 1 kHz up to 20 kHz they are usable if
some care is taken in construction (iron in thin laminations
with insulation between sheets).

At frequencies below 50 Hz, the usual issue is the effectiveness of the
copper wiring, which has to be made thin (but with insulation around it).
Thin wires are prone to breakage, and the insulation thickness starts
to crowd out the copper, which means the electrical resistance of the
copper (in a given winding throat) becomes too high for efficiency.

Traditionally, 400 Hz was deemed
the 'sweet spot' for aircraft transformers, motors, generators.

Permanent magnet rotors can be OK at higher frequency, but only in
conjunction with a soft magnetic material for the stator; the magnetic
field in the output coils MUST change, or no generation of current takes
place.  Iron-based magnetic materials are still the limiting factor.

Ferrite (magnetic oxides) can go to higher frequency without losses
due to electrical conduction, being nonconductive.   The magnetization
of ferrites is, however, inferior to that of iron.   Generators are also possible without soft magnetic materials, and with superconducting coils are efficient
and lightweight, but there are reliability issues with cooling.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. So, eddy currents are dependent on frequency of magnetic field change? And why in fact core separation doesn't help to cope them on higher frequencies?

Comment: Also, 120 000 rpm is 2 000 rps, so the frequency of generated current should be 2kHz. Am I right?  If so, the this design might be used on engines running at 60 000 rpm at maximum thrust. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what the real limit is, on frequency of generated current; there have been advances (metallic glass, for example) in magnetic materials since the 400 Hz standardization, and weight efficiency isn't the only limit (there's also cooling of the iron).   Most generators have several poles, so at four electric cycles per revolution,  1 kHz may correspond to 15000 rpm.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction gearing is necessary because electric generators have, in general, much lower revolutions per sec than turbojet engines. Direct generation of electric power by spinning magnets mounted on the shaft has at least 3 problems: (1) Heavy rotating magnets are an additional impediment to the air (gas) flow in the turbine and might also have some material reliability problems  (2) Permanent magnets lose their magnetism above a certain (Curie) temperature (3) The electric coils with insulating wires in (hot) walls have to be close to the rotating magnets which also might cause reliability problems.

Comment: Indeed generators rotate much slower. The question was - why? Considering problems you've stated, (1) yes, but you don't have to have the same weight as in a geared generator rotating. Most probably this will give pretty same load and inertia as a geared generator. (2) You are right! This is one of the most serious concerns. Still, some engines have cooler areas which do not exceed Curie point for some modern rare-earth magnets. (3) Must serious problem I see is heating and following thermal expansion of the stator, you're right!